# Powershell select problems

Tags: powershell, select, expression

I am trying to get all disks that have free space above 10%. For some reason, at the end it prints only name and capacity, without the other part of select ? If I remove the @expression, it prints size in "bits", any ideas ?

```
gwmi Win32_Volume | where {$_.Name –like "C:\"} | ft Name, 
  @{ Name="Capacity" ; Expression = { "{0:N1}" -f ( $_.Capacity /1gb)}}
  @{ Name="FreeSpace" ; Expression = { "{0:N1}" -f ( $_.FreeSpace/1gb)}}, 
  @{ Name="PercentFree" ; Expression = { "{0:P1}" -f (1 - $_.FreeSpace/ $_.Capacity) }} |
    select Name, Capacity, FreeSpace,  PercentFree | where {$_.PercentFree –gt 10 }  

Name  Capacity
C:\      465.4
```

Comment: 1 - (free/capacity) = percent used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Format-Table takes your output and make it's all nice and fancy in the console but it also cuts off your access to your output. Any formatting you need to do should always happen at the end after you've got the data you want to format.

you were close, a few small changes and i got your code to work like so (You're also missing a comma on the second line :P ):

```
gwmi Win32_Volume | where {$_.Name –like "C:\"} | Select Name,
    @{ Name="Capacity" ; Expression = { "{0:N1}" -f ( $_.Capacity /1gb)}},
    @{ Name="FreeSpace" ; Expression = { "{0:N1}" -f ( $_.FreeSpace/1gb)}}, 
    @{ Name="PercentFree" ; Expression = { "{0:P1}" -f (1 -   $_.FreeSpace/ $_.Capacity) }}  | 
    where {$_.PercentFree –gt 10 } | ft Name, Capacity, FreeSpace,  PercentFree
```

Get Raw Data -> Select-Object or Where-Object as many times as needed -> Format

Comment: perfect ! Big thanks :)
The actual task is to perform it on multiple stations, and I'd rather not scroll over a hundred rows of disk space to find those below thresholds.
I know how to do that, but it was a comma and a format-table that didn't work :)
Thanks again ! Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You're using FT early, then trying to select-object when there are no objects.

Here is a function that grabs the drive info, and calculates the percent free, and adds the percent free to the drive object, and returns the custom object.

```
function drivePercentage {
    param( [string]$ComputerName )

    $drives = gwmi Win32_Volume -Filter "DriveType = 3"

    foreach ($drive in $drives) {
        $PercentFree = [Math]::round($drive.freespace / $drive.Capacity*1000)/1000
    $drive | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name PercentFree -Value $PercentFree

    Write-Output $drive

    }

}

drivePercentage | FT Name,
    @{ Name="Capacity   " ; Expression = { "{0:N2} GB" -f ($_.Capacity /1gb)}},
    @{ Name="FreeSpace  " ; Expression = { "{0:N2} GB" -f ($_.FreeSpace/1gb)}}, 
    @{ Name="PercentFree" ; Expression = { "{0:P1}" -f ($_.PercentFree)} }
```